# why does my neutered bunny spray urine?

Tags: rabbits

My bunny is neutered, but keeps spraying urine all over my home and his own cage. It’s annoying, and I have to clean the areas many times a day. How can I stop it? Is it happening because he's sick?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! How old was the rabbit, when it was spayed? And how long is it spayed now? What kind of cleaning treatment do you use?

Comment: he was about 9-10 months i guess when he got spayed. now he’s 2 years old . i use a fabric to clean places then use water and vinegar spray to get rid of the smell. he wasn’t like this before tho. he suddenly became like this and started to spray alot.

Comment: you can just spray a mixture of vinegar and water and spray at place where he poops next time he will not do it . I have used this for litter training my bunny.

Comment: I am sorry I have no finite answer... Spraying urine is a way to mark the territory. So getting rid of the rabbits smell in a rigid way, could provoke the rabbit to spray again. Maybe you use a new smell to clean? But also the rabbit should see a vet, to be sure there is no health issue, causing the rabbit to "can not hold the urine". Another point: think about to get a second rabbit as company. Humans can never replace a rabbit-rabbit bond.

Comment: yeah thank u sm for ur response

Comment: Is this a new behavior? What is his living arrangement?